# JavaFX, why are the pixel values in anchor panes double? Also what happens if you put in 10.5 for example?

Tags: java, javafx, anchor, pane

Recently I started working with javaFX anchor panes and I saw that the distance value is a double. Now my question is why did they chose a double instead of an int? I mean it's the number of pixels and you can't move the content by half a pixel as far as I know. A little example:

```
AnchorPane.setTopAnchor(something, 10.5);
```

In this example it would set the top anchor to 10.5 pixel. So again, why did they chose to make it a double and what exactly do I change when I put in 10.5 instead of 10.0?

Comment: A scalable geometry, in fact more real life. A diagonal line goes through parts of pixels, the same as letter glyphs. And then rotation & scaling. Font sizes first came with non-integral heights, and better rendering by partial pixel shifts. Then there were subpixels

Answer (score 1):

Layout coordinates in JavaFX are all `double`s. Depending on the properties of the the final position of the child may actually be rounded to an integral value (see [the `snapToPixel` property](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/11/javafx.graphics/javafx/scene/layout/Region.html#snapToPixelProperty)). (`AnchorPane` does not seem to do this, but simply uses non-integral values for the positions/widths of children.)

Furthermore there may be transforms that align the node to pixels, e.g. scaling by a factor 2.

In general it's not possible to always align the "node pixels" to the display pixels perfectly in all cases. (Just consider a rotation of by 45°.)

If a part of a `Node` does not completely cover a pixel after all transformations have been applied, the result is the color of the node being drawn with an opacity that depends on the part of the pixel being covered by the node, e.g. the edge of a rectangle positioned at 10.5 results in the node's color being drawn on "pixel 10" with half opacity.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is the real reason for that, but as said in the docs

> AnchorPane allows the edges of child nodes to be anchored to an offset from the anchor pane's edges. If the anchor pane has a border and/or padding set, the offsets will be measured from the inside edge of those insets. [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/layout/AnchorPane.html)

so it seems that it calculates the difference between the node child and the anchor panes's edges to determine where to place the node child and distance calcualte are always calculated float/double formats !

**But in the code it seems seamless they both do the same thing**